# Question ban revoked

Tags: support, post-ban

My question ban was revoked. I don't know how or why. Can anyone tell me why? Because I didn't answer any questions, only one of my questions was upvoted, nothing else.
Also, does this mean that I won't get a question ban again?

Comment: interesting, _post-ban_ make sense both for _post_ as in "post-apocalyptic" (meaning after-ban) and for the common meaning (post as posts). I hope you didn't chose it because the former ;)

Comment: Aarrgh! An ambiguous tag! Burninate! Burninate!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your question ban was revoked with a single upvote, that means you were very near the ban threshold. The upvote may have taken you over the threshold, but it can't be by far, and yes you could be question banned again.

I'd advise you to follow the suggestions given to you in the [ban link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/162704), improve your existing posts and provide some *good* answers. Hopefully you won't get question banned again in the future, it's completely up to you.

Comment: But it says in meta, that your questions need several downvotes, but only 1 question of mine had a downvote, so how did I get banned?

Comment: @RohitShinde I see at least two downvoted questions in [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1453258/rohit-shinde?tab=questions&sort=newest), and a large number of zero scored ones. And deleted questions count as well, although I can't see them.

Comment: I didn't delete questions, because I don't know how to delete questions. Okay, I will keep this in mind.

Comment: @RohitShinde We're not going to reveal the exact formulas we use. :) But let's just say that voting is a measure of how much the community appreciates your posts, so a good preventative measure is to follow the guidance Yannis linked to and attract upvotes on your existing and future posts to avoid getting blocked again.

Comment: Yes, I will certainly follow this advice :)