# Has anyone ever come back from a banned account?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I found out I was hacked the other day and asked a question about the WSO 2.5 I found on my server. Apparently this wasn't the place -- it got massive downvotes, and now I cannot ask questions.

Does anyone know of users that have came back from this? I've been answering questions trying to get upvotes, but so far I still cannot ask.

It wasn't like I intentionally misused the site. Now I'm stuck on a programming question and can't ask it where I always have.

Comment: A quick note: That one post was likely just the straw that broke the proverbial camel's back; it just happened to be the trigger, but other posts were likely involved in calculating the ban.

Comment: Is it one account for all stack sites? I couldn't log in for some reason and created one through gmail (now it's showing this account for here and kcdwayne on stackoverflow.com)

Comment: You can see this relative : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158093/post-ban-not-removed-after-editing-my-questions/158097#158097  and this one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168263/question-ban-meter-feature-request/168269#168269

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People work their way out of a question ban all the time.

The best thing you can do is to improve the quality of your old questions; however, tt may also be helpful to get a moderator to undelete any questions that you have deleted because deleting too many of your own questions can also trigger a question ban.

Comment: Do you have evidence of "all the time"? I can recall two users on Meta who say that they have.

Comment: I will try to look, but it is definitely possible and I have seen people thank everyone who helped them once they did. Unfortunately, many of those questions are deleted so it may be hard to find examples.

Comment: [Question ban revoked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142629) is one, but I'm not so sure how many others there are.

Comment: Most of the ones I have seen were stemmed off of someone asking how to get our of a post ban because they didnt read the email. Unfortunately, those questions are usually deleted afterwards form what I have seen.

Comment: There's at least ten of those in the sidebar right now --->